# Testing vi Editor Functionality with Python?

Tags: python, linux, automated-tests, vi

How do I write an automated test that can check the vi editor is properly working programmed using Python?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What does _"properly working programmed"_? Are you trying to check if it is installed? Are you trying to check if it has a certain plugin? Also, you need to show what you've tried please.

Comment: You type python code into the computer instructing it to test that the vi editor is properly working then run it. Broad questions deserve broad answers. Please consult the stackoverflow posting guidelines -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Sorry for being broad I'm not sure where to start. I want to ensure all the components of vi work as they should on a development of a custom Linux OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your script containing vi command as follows.

```
           cat script.sh
           vi abc.txt <<INPUT                                                                                                                               
           i                                                                                                                                                        
           Line 1                                                                                                                                                   
           Line 2                                                                                                                                                   
           ^[                                                                                                                                                       
           ZZ                                                                                                                                                       
           INPUT
```

Use the python subprocess.check_call to check the status of execution

```
subprocess.check_call(["script.sh" , "arg1"])
```

This will Run the command(script.sh) with arguments(if needed). Waits for command to complete. If the return code was zero then returns,
 otherwise raises `CalledProcessError Exception`.